# Get Taxonomy Term Title by it's URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, urls

I have a URL - `http://localhost/products/product-name/` and I want to use this URL to retrieve the title `Product Name`

This is out of loop, so the URL provided is all I have to work from. `Product Name` is obviously the name of the term, which has the URL `http://localhost/products/product-name/` I just need it so I can print it out on a particular place on the website.

The url above denotes the taxonomy as `products` but this is a rewrite of `product_type` - I'm not sure if this'll affect the solution.

Comment: My Work Around at the moment, is to run a str_replace on the slug, which I retrieved by regex - then force Capitalize in CSS. Not ideal, but serves the idea well enough. The issue with this method is if the Slug is different to the page title.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from trivial. URL processing is not straightforward and mostly buried in `WP->parse_request()` which is not popular to reuse.

There is more useful [`url_to_postid()`](http://queryposts.com/function/url_to_postid/) function, but it's limited to posts and does not process URL to other things.

If really necessary this would take fork of that function to deal with terms. However more practical solution would probably be to pass some extra data in some form and don't mess with URL at all.

Comment: I can extract the slug from the URL, as I have done with simple regex - all the links on my site follow a strict pattern, so errors are unlikely. I would have assumed I'd be able to return the rewrite slug of the terms if I returned the entire taxonomy - I could then use this to compare against.